# Linking errors when trying to link libclang in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, dll, linker, clang, visual-studio-2015

What I'm trying to do is to build this library:
https://github.com/AustinBrunkhorst/CPP-Reflection
All is going well until I get to linking against libclang where this happens:

```
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_CXXMethod_isStatic
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCursorType
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_Cursor_getMangling
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCXXAccessSpecifier
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_Cursor_getStorageClass
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCursorSpelling
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_visitChildren
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getTypedefDeclUnderlyingType
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCursorDisplayName
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_CXXMethod_isConst
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_isCursorDefinition
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCursorLexicalParent
1>Cursor.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCursorResultType
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_isConstQualifiedType
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getNumArgTypes
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getTypeDeclaration
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getTypeSpelling
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getArgType
1>CursorType.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCanonicalType
1>MetaUtils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_disposeString
1>MetaUtils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getCString
1>ReflectionParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_getTranslationUnitCursor
1>ReflectionParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile
1>ReflectionParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_createIndex
1>ReflectionParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_disposeIndex
1>ReflectionParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_clang_disposeTranslationUnit
```

I'm building 64-bit release, and I have build manually llvm/clang from sources also in 64 bit/release mode.
I dunno if that matters (?), but I'm using master branch of clang from github. Considering that everything passes until linking stage I assumed that, everything should be ok with master branch.

I'm using Visual Stduio 2015.

In project options I have added Additional Library Directories to point where clang have *.lib files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to specifying their paths in `Linker ->additional library directories`, you need to explicitly enlist the specific `.lib` files you are linking to in the `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` section of the properties dialog.

Also, check once again that you have the correct path and version (x86 vs x64) for the lib files.

In the absence of the lib files, the linker could not resolve names (symbols) to their implementation, hence the `unresolved symbol` linker error.

If you are interested in knowing further, here is a good resource - http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html